# NodeJs & mongodb - script does not end

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need my script to end/exit after it is finished and after several tests I thought the problem was  my mongodb-class, which connection i never closed. (when I commented out the class btw it's usage, the script ran through and exited like I want it)

But after I have implemented a closing-method, my script still is alive and I don't know why?

this is my mongo-class:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

class MongodbClient {

  constructor(cfg) {
  
    // CONNECT TO MONGO-ENGINE
    this.client = new MongoClient(cfg.mongoUrl, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    this.client.connect();

    // CONNECT TO DB
    this.db = this.client.db(cfg.mongoDbName);        

  }

  // Close connection
  async end() {

    this.client.close()

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(true)
    })
    
  }

  // .. some mehtods

}


module.exports = {
  MongodbClient: MongodbClient
}
```

in my main-script I call a function `dosomething()` at which end the script needs to exit:

```
parser.dosomething().then(async() => {    
  await mongo.end()    
})
```

but the sctipt still lives? why is that?

Comment: ... `async end()` resolves immediately (as you not awaiting the `this.client.close()` maybe ..? .. so if You made the `end` method `asyn` - should you await `this.client.close()` before returning the "resolving" promise ..? (

Answer (score 1):

### Promise-Ception

Your `end` method returns another `Promise` within a `Promise`

```js
async end() {
  /* ... */
  return true
}
```

This async function returns a Promise by itself. For async functions it's important to return something at some point.

In your `dosomething` method you do the correct thing and use `await` to resolve the Promise.

```js
await mongo.end();
```

However it doesn't stop there. The first Promise (`async end`) returns another Promise

```js
// ...
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return resolve(true)
});
// ...
```

To completely resolve everything, your `dosomething` method should eventually do this :

```js
const anotherPromise = await mongo.end();
await anotherPromise();
```

By this time you will realize that [`client.close()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/MongoClient.html#close) as well returns a Promise and should be resolved. The whole thing is a bit messy IMHO.

---

### Simplify things

Try this

```js
async end() {
  try {
    await this.client.close();
    return true;
  } catch (ex) {
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

```
parser.dosomething().then(async () => {    
  try {
    const closed = await mongo.end();
    console.log("connection closed");
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
  }
});
```

Remember to use `try ... catch` blocks when using `async/await` . If the result is still the same  then the problem lies somewhere else probably.

---

### Simplify some more

```js
end() { return this.client.close() }
```

Now your `end` method just returns the unresolved Promise from `client.close`. **Please Note**, I removed the `async` prefix from the `end` method as it is not needed.

```
await mongo.end();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for that! :) I think I understood and I made the changes. According to my console.log-journey it all now runs sync and after that I get my last console.log-message.. but the script still won't exit :/